Doubts in coding with STM32 NUCLEO BOARD
I am using STM32 CUBE IDE for coding with NUCLEO-WL55JC2 development board , it has STM32 WL55JC controlller with two ARM processor cortex M0+ and cortex M4. i working for the first time with double core controller in STM32 CUBE IDE.while i am creating a new project by selecting the  board. it is creating like the image below ..
enter image description here
I dont know how to dump the code . But i am trying to dump the code for the controller by building the code for CORTEX M4 and trying to dump into the controller , and i am getting this error
enter image description here
i dont know how to run this , so i am going through some excisting samples , the project setup is completely different from what i have created . like this
enter image description here
I dont know what mistake i am doing , i need solution for this .
I want to create a proper setup for NUCLEO BOARD(WL55JC2) to work with STM32 CUBE IDE for unning the code as well as debugging

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text (using code formatting), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and many more reasons. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.
